# Convenient way to define all comparison operators for class with one numeric data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison-operators

If I have a type that consists of a single numeric data member (say, an `int`) and various methods, is there a convenient way to tell the compiler to automatically generate all the obvious comparison operators?

I.e., instead of this (using `inline` instead of `constexpr` for C++03, of course):

```
class MyValueType
{
    private:
        int myvalue;
    public:
        constexpr bool operator<(MyValueType rhs) const { return myvalue < rhs.myvalue; }
        constexpr bool operator>(MyValueType rhs) const { return myvalue > rhs.myvalue; }
        constexpr bool operator>=(MyValueType rhs) const { return myvalue >= rhs.myvalue; }
        constexpr bool operator==(MyValueType rhs) const { return myvalue == rhs.myvalue; }
        /// .... etc
}
```

I want something like Ruby's Comparable mixin, which basically allows you to define *one* operator and let Ruby take care of the rest. And I'd even assume that the compiler-generated versions would probably be better than mine: should `rhs` be a `const` ref for each case? Should I define versions that take forwarding references? What if I forget one of the operators? Etc.

So...does something like this exist?

(Please forgive me if this is a duplicate; I assumed someone would have already asked this somewhere, because it seems like an obvious feature to want, but I can't find any.)

**EDIT:** Automatic generation of comparison operators has been proposed as a feature: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3950.html

Comment: A simple `#define` would do.

Comment: C++11 doesn't let you define `constexpr` member functions...

Comment: @MooingDuck `#define` what, exactly? Do you mean something like `#define MyType int`? That would be better accomplished with a typedef or (in C++11) a type alias, and in any case that's not exactly what I'm doing. (What about static members and member functions?)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos It does if you have a literal type, which I do. If it's a non-literal type, just use `inline` instead. (Obviously auto-generating the functions would take care of this....)

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually, did you mean that I could `#define` a macro for expanding into the appropriate operator functions? That makes a bit more sense, and I may end up doing that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ way of doing this is to use a tag type and ADL. Here is a quick example:

```
namespace relational {
    struct tag {};

    template <typename T>
    bool operator== (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return !(rhs < lhs) && !(lhs < rhs); }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator!= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator> (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return rhs < lhs; }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator<= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return !(rhs < lhs); }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator>= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) { return !(lhs < rhs); }
}

struct foo: relational::tag {
    int value;
    foo(int value): value(value) {}
    bool operator< (foo const& other) const { return this->value < other.value; }
};

#include <iostream>
void compare(foo f0, foo f1) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << f0.value << " == " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 == f1) << '\n'
              << f0.value << " != " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 != f1) << '\n'
              << f0.value << " <  " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 <  f1) << '\n'
              << f0.value << " <= " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 <= f1) << '\n'
              << f0.value << " >  " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 >  f1) << '\n'
              << f0.value << " >= " << f1.value << " => " << (f0 >= f1) << '\n'
        ;
}
int main() {
    compare(foo(1), foo(2));
    compare(foo(2), foo(2));
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck: to be fair, to do it properly the operators in the namespace should use SFINAE to only e found if the argument type is actually derived from the tag type! Otherwise they'll also be found if the type is used as a template argument which is not necessarily desirable.

Comment: Note that many of these operator definitions are *wrong* if `value` is a floating-point instead of an `int` (they are all right if `value` is an `int`). The problem is that a floating-point can be NaN, and comparing a NaN to anything returns `false`. This breaks many mathematical equivalences (such as `x <= y` equivalent to `!(x > y)` and `x != y` equivalent to `!(x == y)`). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/32039711/855050.

Comment: @becko: no dispute here: the above functions are suitable if  `operator<()` yields a strict weak order. For floating point types that's not the code. A corresponding set of operators, in a different namespace with its own tag, could be defined to deal with cases where a null value like the floating point NaN need to be considered. The operators would probably use a suitable property (`is_null()`) in addition to `operator<()` to efficiently compare objects. Of course, for floating point types there is no need to use these as they have their operators already defined.

Comment: We usually want comparison operators to be friend functions. Isn't using this approach only works when you make at least one of the comparison operators a member function? I think it's a compelling reason to make them members instead of friend.

Comment: @DDG: The approach certainly works as posted and achieves the mix-in objective. Trying to make the mixing operators member functions certainly doesn't work via inheritance. It probably does work using CRTP, though, but that is inverting the inheritance direction. With C++20 there is now also `operator<=>` which removes most of the need of using such a mix-in: you'd write two member operator, i.e., an equality (`operator==`) and a relation (`operator<=>`) and you'd get the remaining operators for free. If the class is holding values you can probably even `= default` these two operators.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at boost operators (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)? It defines a bunch of templates to help you automatically define operators in your class.

Answer (score 0):

While in general ADL/KL is blessed way to go (kudos to Dietmar Kuhl), there is Curiously Recurring Template Pattern which might be used to facilitate such task (I've implemented not all methods, but idea is clear enough, I hope)

```
template <typename D> struct B
{
    bool operator==(const D& rhs) const { return !(rhs < *(const D*)this ) && !(*(const D*)this < rhs); }
    bool operator!=(const D& rhs) const { return !(*(const D*)this == rhs); }
};

struct D: public B<D>
{
    int _value;

    D(int value): _value(value) {}

    bool operator< (const D& rhs) const {return this->_value < rhs._value;}
};

int main()
{
    D a(1);
    D b(2);
    D c(1);

    std::cout << (a == b) << " " << (a == c) << " " << (a != c) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```