# Best way to avoid code duplication defining comparison operators `<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=`, but taking into account NaNs?

Tags: c++, floating-point, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I mathematics, `x <= y` is equivalent to `!(x > y)`. This is true for floating-point arithmetic, *in most cases*, but not always. When `x` or `y` is NaN, `x <= y` is **not** equivalent to `!(x > y)`, because comparing a `NaN` to anything always returns `false`. But still, `x <= y <=> !(x > y)` is true most of the time.

Now, suppose I am writing a class that contains floating-point values, and I want to define comparison operators for this class. For definiteness, suppose I am writing a high-precision floating-point number, which uses one or more `double` values internally to store the high-precision number. Mathematically, the definition of `x < y` for this class already defines all the other operators (if I am being consistent with the usual semantics of the comparison operators). But `NaN`s break this mathematical nicety. So maybe I am forced to write many of these operators separately, just to take into account NaNs. But is there a better way? My question is: *How can I avoid code duplication as much as possible and still respect the behavior of `NaN`?*

Related: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/utility/operators.htm. How does boost/operators resolve this issue?

Note: I tagged this question `c++` because that's what I understand. Please write examples in that language.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269216/855050. That answer presents a satisfactory solution for integral types. But it doesn't work for floating-point because of NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a similar technique as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269216/1120273) which defines comparison function based on `operator<()` yielding a strict weak order. For types with a null value which is meant to have comparisons always yield `false` the operations would be defined in terms of `operator<()` providing a strict weak order on all non-null value and an `is_null()` test.

For example, the code could look like this:

```
namespace nullable_relational {
    struct tag {};

    template <typename T>
    bool non_null(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return !is_null(lhs) && !is_null(rhs);
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator== (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return non_null(lhs, rhs) && !(rhs < lhs) && !(lhs < rhs);
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator!= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return non_null(lhs, rhs) || !(lhs == rhs);
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator> (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return non_null(lhs, rhs) && rhs < lhs;
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator<= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return non_null(lhs, rhs) && !(rhs < lhs);
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator>= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return non_null(lhs, rhs) && !(lhs < rhs);
    }
}
```

It would be use like this:

```
#include <cmath>
class foo
    : private nullable_relational::tag {
    double value;
public:
    foo(double value): value(value) {}
    bool is_null() const { return std::isnan(this->value); }
    bool operator< (foo const& other) const { return this->value < other.value; }
};
bool is_null(foo const& value) { return value.is_null(); }
```

A variation of the same theme could be an implementation in terms of one compare function which is parameterized by the comparison function and which is responsible to appropriately feed the comparison function with parameters. For example:

```
namespace compare_relational {
    struct tag {};

    template <typename T>
    bool operator== (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs == rhs; });
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator!= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs != rhs; });
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool operator< (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs < rhs; });
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator> (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; });
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator<= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs <= rhs; });
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool operator>= (T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return compare(lhs, rhs, [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return lhs >= rhs; });
    }
}

class foo
    : private compare_relational::tag {
    double value;
public:
    foo(double value): value(value) {}

    template <typename Compare>
    friend bool compare(foo const& f0, foo const& f1, Compare&& predicate) {
        return predicate(f0.value, f1.value);
    }
};
```

I could imagine having multiple of these operation-generating namespaces to support a suitable choice for common situations. Another option could be a different ordering than floating points and, e.g., consider a null value the smallest or the largest value. Since some people use NaN-boxing it may even be reasonable to provide an order on different NaN values and arrange the NaN values at suitable places. For example, using the underlying bit representation provide a total order of floating point values which may be suitable for using the objects as a key in an ordered container although the order might be different from the order created by `operator<()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your operator< you'll need to handle the NaN case.  For ordering and comparison purposes, if you treat a NaN as less than any non-NaN, you can do something like this:

```
bool operator<(double l, double r) {
    if (isnan(l)) {
        if (isnan(r)) return false; // NaN == NaN
        return true;        // NaN < rational
    }
    return l < r;       // if r is NaN will return false, which is how we've defined it
}
```

The other operators are defined in terms of operator< and require no manually written code.

Comment: But `NaN < x` should always be `false`.

Comment: Are you wanting x > Nan to be false or true?  To maintain symmetry with < it should be true.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm NaN `op` <anything> is always false.

Comment: @Mark B I know it is, it reads like OP is using doubles in a larger context and needs to handle NaNs in those.  So maybe I'm unclear on what OP is asking.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I want to repro the usual convention in my class, the usual convention being that `NaN < x` and `x < NaN` are always `false`.

Comment: OK, that's not what I originally understood from your question.  Given that, my solution would be similar to @Dietmar Kühl's where each operator checks for NaNs but I'd use a comparison that can return less, equal, or greater (like strcmp) to avoid comparing twice for equality.